# UITabViewController: Selected Tab, Update UIViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a simple `UIViewController` in a `UITabViewController`.

The am looking to have the `UIViewController` update certain items on itself when a user taps the tab that it is in.

What event in the `UIViewController` can I handle which will be notified `everytime` the viewcontroller is made visible by the `UITabViewController`?

Comment: Did you try `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get calls to `viewWilAppear` and `viewDidAppear`. You said 'events' but is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I write iPhone software using Microsoft .NET so in that realm we have Events. see: http://Xamarin.com